# Compilation of gtkdialog with gcc fails on Solaris (cc1: error: invalid option `t')

Tags: compiling, solaris, gcc

I have Solaris 10 x86 just installed on my VBox, but I have problem with `make` and `make install` command. When I try to run this command I got error related to gcc compiler option `-t`:
Here is config.log

```
 $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = unknown
uname -m = i86pc
uname -r = 5.10
uname -s = SunOS
uname -v = Generic_147148-26

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = System = SunOS
Node = unknown
Release = 5.10
KernelID = Generic_147148-26
Machine = i86pc
BusType = <unknown>
Serial = <unknown>
Users = <unknown>
OEM# = 0
Origin# = 1
NumCPU = 1

/bin/arch              = i86pc
/usr/bin/arch -k       = i86pc
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/gnome/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /opt/netscape
PATH: /usr/ccs/bin
PATH: //bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/openwin/bin
PATH: /usr/ucb
PATH: //bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /root/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/csw/bin
PATH: /opt/csw/sbin
PATH: /opt/csw/gcc3/bin
PATH: /usr/sfw/sbin
PATH: /usr/sfw/bin
PATH: /opt/csw/mysql5/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1392: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:1447: result: ./install-sh -c
configure:1458: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:1501: result: yes
configure:1566: checking for gawk
configure:1595: result: no
configure:1566: checking for mawk
configure:1595: result: no
configure:1566: checking for nawk
configure:1582: found //bin/nawk
configure:1592: result: nawk
configure:1602: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:1622: result: yes
configure:1792: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:1801: result: no
configure:1830: checking for style of include used by make
configure:1858: result: GNU
configure:1929: checking for gcc
configure:1955: result: gcc
configure:2199: checking for C compiler version
configure:2202: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
gcc (GCC) 3.3.2
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2205: $? = 0
configure:2207: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.3.2/specs
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.2
configure:2210: $? = 0
configure:2212: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
gcc: `-V' option must have argument
configure:2215: $? = 1
configure:2238: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2241: gcc  -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2244: $? = 0
configure:2290: result: a.out
configure:2295: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2301: ./a.out
configure:2304: $? = 0
configure:2321: result: yes
configure:2328: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:2330: result: no
configure:2333: checking for suffix of executables
configure:2335: gcc -o conftest  -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2338: $? = 0
configure:2363: result: 
configure:2369: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2390: gcc -c  -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2393: $? = 0
configure:2415: result: o
configure:2419: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:2443: gcc -c  -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2449: $? = 0
configure:2453: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2456: $? = 0
configure:2459: test -s conftest.o
configure:2462: $? = 0
configure:2475: result: yes
configure:2481: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:2502: gcc -c -g -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2508: $? = 0
configure:2512: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2515: $? = 0
configure:2518: test -s conftest.o
configure:2521: $? = 0
configure:2532: result: yes
configure:2549: checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C
configure:2619: gcc  -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:2625: $? = 0
configure:2629: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2632: $? = 0
configure:2635: test -s conftest.o
configure:2638: $? = 0
configure:2656: result: none needed
configure:2674: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:2: error: parse error before "me"
configure:2680: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| #ifndef __cplusplus
|   choke me
| #endif
configure:2815: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:2905: result: gcc3
configure:2923: checking for library containing strerror
configure:2953: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:2959: $? = 0
configure:2963: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:2966: $? = 0
configure:2969: test -s conftest
configure:2972: $? = 0
configure:3042: result: none required
configure:3095: checking for gcc
configure:3121: result: gcc
configure:3365: checking for C compiler version
configure:3368: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
gcc (GCC) 3.3.2
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3371: $? = 0
configure:3373: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.3.2/specs
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.2
configure:3376: $? = 0
configure:3378: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
gcc: `-V' option must have argument
configure:3381: $? = 1
configure:3384: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3440: result: yes
configure:3446: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3497: result: yes
configure:3514: checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C
configure:3621: result: none needed
configure:3639: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:2: error: parse error before "me"
configure:3645: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| #ifndef __cplusplus
|   choke me
| #endif
configure:3780: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:3870: result: gcc3
configure:3895: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3930: gcc -E -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c
configure:3936: $? = 0
configure:3968: gcc -E -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c
conftest.c:11:28: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
configure:3974: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "pipas@linux.pte.hu"
| #define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
| #define VERSION "0.7.9"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4013: result: gcc -E
configure:4037: gcc -E -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c
configure:4043: $? = 0
configure:4075: gcc -E -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c
conftest.c:11:28: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
configure:4081: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "pipas@linux.pte.hu"
| #define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
| #define VERSION "0.7.9"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:4125: checking for egrep
configure:4135: result: egrep
configure:4140: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:4165: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:4171: $? = 0
configure:4175: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:4178: $? = 0
configure:4181: test -s conftest.o
configure:4184: $? = 0
configure:4273: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:4276: $? = 0
configure:4278: ./conftest
configure:4281: $? = 0
configure:4296: result: yes
configure:4310: checking for flex
configure:4326: found /usr/sfw/bin/flex
configure:4336: result: flex
configure:4349: checking for yywrap in -lfl
configure:4379: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c -lfl   >&5
ld: fatal: library -lfl: not found
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to conftest
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4385: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.7.9"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "pipas@linux.pte.hu"
| #define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
| #define VERSION "0.7.9"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any gcc2 internal prototype to avoid an error.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| /* We use char because int might match the return type of a gcc2
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| char yywrap ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| yywrap ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4411: result: no
configure:4416: checking for yywrap in -ll
configure:4446: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c -ll   >&5
configure:4452: $? = 0
configure:4456: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:4459: $? = 0
configure:4462: test -s conftest
configure:4465: $? = 0
configure:4478: result: yes
configure:4489: checking lex output file root
configure:4500: flex conftest.l
configure:4503: $? = 0
configure:4515: result: lex.yy
configure:4520: checking whether yytext is a pointer
configure:4536: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  -ll >&5
configure:4542: $? = 0
configure:4546: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:4549: $? = 0
configure:4552: test -s conftest
configure:4555: $? = 0
configure:4569: result: yes
configure:4587: checking for bison
configure:4603: found /usr/sfw/bin/bison
configure:4613: result: bison -y
configure:4676: checking for pkg-config
configure:4694: found //bin/pkg-config
configure:4706: result: //bin/pkg-config
configure:4721: checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0
configure:4724: result: yes
configure:4735: checking for GTK
configure:4743: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$pkg_modules"
configure:4746: $? = 0
configure:4761: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$pkg_modules"
configure:4764: $? = 0
configure:4840: result: yes
configure:4850: checking for GTHREAD
configure:4858: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$pkg_modules"
configure:4861: $? = 0
configure:4876: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "$pkg_modules"
configure:4879: $? = 0
configure:4955: result: yes
configure:4965: checking for GLADE_LIB
configure:4974: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "\
          $glade_lib"
configure:4978: $? = 0
configure:4995: $PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "\
          $glade_lib"
configure:4999: $? = 0
configure:5042: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for sys/types.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for stdlib.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for string.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for memory.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for strings.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for inttypes.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for stdint.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5067: checking for unistd.h
configure:5083: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5089: $? = 0
configure:5093: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5096: $? = 0
configure:5099: test -s conftest.o
configure:5102: $? = 0
configure:5113: result: yes
configure:5139: checking locale.h usability
configure:5151: gcc -c -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c >&5
configure:5157: $? = 0
configure:5161: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5164: $? = 0
configure:5167: test -s conftest.o
configure:5170: $? = 0
configure:5180: result: yes
configure:5184: checking locale.h presence
configure:5194: gcc -E -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include conftest.c
configure:5200: $? = 0
configure:5220: result: yes
configure:5255: checking for locale.h
configure:5262: result: yes
configure:5283: checking for setlocale
configure:5340: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include  conftest.c  >&5
configure:5346: $? = 0
configure:5350: test -z 
             || test ! -s conftest.err
configure:5353: $? = 0
configure:5356: test -s conftest
configure:5359: $? = 0
configure:5371: result: yes
configure:5507: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by gtkdialog config.status 0.7.9, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on unknown

config.status:709: creating Makefile
config.status:709: creating gtkdialog.spec
config.status:709: creating src/Makefile
config.status:709: creating doc/Makefile
config.status:709: creating examples/Makefile
config.status:813: creating config.h
config.status:925: config.h is unchanged
config.status:1105: executing depfiles commands

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_c_compiler_gnu=yes
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GLADE_LIB_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTHREAD_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_exeext=
ac_cv_func_setlocale=yes
ac_cv_header_inttypes_h=yes
ac_cv_header_locale_h=yes
ac_cv_header_memory_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdc=yes
ac_cv_header_stdint_h=yes
ac_cv_header_stdlib_h=yes
ac_cv_header_string_h=yes
ac_cv_header_strings_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_stat_h=yes
ac_cv_header_sys_types_h=yes
ac_cv_header_unistd_h=yes
ac_cv_lib_fl_yywrap=no
ac_cv_lib_l_yywrap=yes
ac_cv_objext=o
ac_cv_path_ac_pt_PKG_CONFIG=//bin/pkg-config
ac_cv_prog_AWK=nawk
ac_cv_prog_CPP='gcc -E'
ac_cv_prog_LEX=flex
ac_cv_prog_YACC='bison -y'
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_cc_g=yes
ac_cv_prog_cc_stdc=
ac_cv_prog_egrep=egrep
ac_cv_prog_lex_root=lex.yy
ac_cv_prog_lex_yytext_pointer=yes
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
ac_cv_search_strerror='none required'
am_cv_CC_dependencies_compiler_type=gcc3
am_cv_prog_cc_stdc=
pkg_cv_GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/libglade-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
pkg_cv_GLADE_LIB_LIBS='-lglade-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lxml2 -lpthread -lz -lsocket -lnsl -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lmlib -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '
pkg_cv_GTHREAD_CFLAGS='-mt -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
pkg_cv_GTHREAD_LIBS='-mt -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '
pkg_cv_GTK_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
pkg_cv_GTK_LIBS='-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lmlib -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run aclocal-1.9'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run tar'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run automake-1.9'
AWK='nawk'
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE='depmode=gcc3'
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP='gcc -E'
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS='-DHAVE_CONFIG_H'
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP='egrep'
EXEEXT=''
GLADE_LIB_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/libglade-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
GLADE_LIB_LIBS='-lglade-2.0 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lxml2 -lpthread -lz -lsocket -lnsl -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lmlib -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '
GTHREAD_CFLAGS='-mt -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
GTHREAD_LIBS='-mt -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '
GTK_CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include  '
GTK_LIBS='-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lmlib -lpangoxft-1.0 -lpangox-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0  '
HAVE_GLADE_LIB='1'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LEX='flex'
LEXLIB='-ll'
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT='lex.yy'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/missing --run makeinfo'
OBJEXT='o'
PACKAGE='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='pipas@linux.pte.hu'
PACKAGE_NAME='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_STRING='gtkdialog 0.7.9'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gtkdialog'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.7.9'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG='//bin/pkg-config'
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='0.7.9'
YACC='bison -y'
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_STRIP=''
ac_pt_PKG_CONFIG='//bin/pkg-config'
am__fastdepCC_FALSE='#'
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host_alias=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
install_sh='/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
mkdir_p='$(mkinstalldirs)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_LOCALE_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_SETLOCALE 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define PACKAGE "gtkdialog"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "pipas@linux.pte.hu"
#define PACKAGE_NAME "gtkdialog"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "gtkdialog 0.7.9"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "gtkdialog"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.7.9"
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define VERSION "0.7.9"
#define YYTEXT_POINTER 1

configure: exit 0
```

After make command I get this below. Guys suggested me to remove `-mt` flag, but then I get other error's.I'm not so good in Solaris, to solve this problem, and still I'm stuck here:

```
bash-3.2# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/src'
make  all-am
make[3]: Entering directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/src'
if gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I..   -I/opt/gnome/include -I/usr/openwin/share/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -mt -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -I/usr/include/libglade-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/openwin/include -I/usr/sfw/include -I/usr/sfw/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include   -DHAVE_GLADE_LIB=1 -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/main.Tpo" -c -o main.o main.c; \
        then mv -f ".deps/main.Tpo" ".deps/main.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/main.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
cc1: error: invalid option `t'
make[3]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/src'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Desktop/gtkdialog-0.7.9'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your makefile is set up to use the Solaris C compiler's options, but you're using `gcc`.  You don't say how your makefile was generated, but replacing `CFLAGS` with something more appropriate will help.  If you used a `configure` script to generate your makefile then I'm a bit confused, as doing `CC=gcc ./configure` should be enough to do the right thing.
2. Your `sudo` is broken because it can't find one of its shared libraries.  It's probably installed but not included in your library path.  Check the output of `crle`, and add `/usr/sfw/lib`, which is where that library probably resides.

Comment: ok, thanks for answer, but how can I change this CFLAGS, with what should I replace it?

Comment: Did you write the makefile, or create it with a `configure` script, or what?

Comment: I want to install aplication gtkdialog, so it was in the package allready...and instruction are to run, ./configure, make and make install

Comment: Try removing the makefile (or just unpack the package again), and doing `CC=gcc ./configure`.

Comment: gcc is seeing the `-mt` option (enable multithread features for cc) as the two options `-m` & `-t` and not knowing what to do with `-t`, so it's the `-mt` option you need to replace.

Comment: replace it in Makefile or where?, just to remove it or replace with something else?